# .net Identity: error trying to change string (GUID?) keys to int

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I have an application (using Identity 2.2) created in VS2015 with the example application (MVC, mvc individual authentication), which I modified following a tutorial to add some custom fields to the users table (using a migration to get added fields into the database).
Then for the rest of the tables (non-Identity ones) I am using EntityFramework database-first to generate CRUD controllers & views etc.
So far so good, everything seems to be working nicely.

Now I am trying to modify it so that the keys for Identity tables are integers instead of GUIDs. I have followed this tutorial (with MVC update 3),
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity#context

but after following the tutorial, when I build and run the solution I get this error when it tries to generate the models

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
> Proyecto.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

I have no idea how to fix it... any help is appreciated.

my Models/IdentityModels.cs:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>

{
    //added custom fields
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaUltModif { get; set; }
    public bool Activo { get; set; }
    public string Notas { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //to fix some conflicts using mysql
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(255);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(255);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().Property(r => r.Name).HasMaxLength(255);
    }

}


//aded for int keys
public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is your problem:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       //your problem is in this line change IdentityRole  to CustomRole 
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().Property(r => r.Name).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
```

**use `CustomRole` instead of `IdentityRole`** because `IdentityRole` defined with string primary key and in `CustomUserRole` you are using `int`

if you go to definition of `IdentityRole` you will find its extended `IdentityRole<string, IdentityUserRole>` and its why you are getting error

**Currected Code:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    //to fix some conflicts using mysql
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(255);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(255);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().Property(r => r.Name).HasMaxLength(255);
}
```

Comment: Great!. that was the problem. Thanks